# socket.io client not receiving broadcasts from server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an instant messaging chat application in the making, and am having problems getting my client to receive data from my server. Could anyone explain to me why this is happening?

**app.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);
var io = socket.listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function(client) {
    client.on("join", function(name) {
        client.set("nickname", name);
        console.log(name + " connected."); // logs name correctly
        client.broadcast.emit("names", name);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var server = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");

            server.on("connect", function(data) {
                nickname = "";
                while (nickname == null || nickname.trim() == "") {
                    nickname = prompt("Enter name");
                }
                server.emit("join", nickname);
            });

            server.on("names", function(data) {
                document.getElementById("txtNames").value = data;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="txtNames"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what a **broadcast** is? When you broadcast a message as a result of an event from a socket, The message is emitted to all connected clients except for the socket who triggered the event. Same is your case. If you want to emit `names` event to your connected client then use

`socket.emit("names", name);` in your app.js

Comment: I see. I was using broadcast because that's what the guy in CodeSchool's node.js course videos was using. Thanks for explaining its true functionality to me, I'll be sure to remember it for the future.

Comment: I can understand. Suppose if you have opened index.html in 3 tabs of your browser, These are 3 connected clients. Now if you use client.broadcast.emit and you trigger 'join' from a client then 'names' event will be fired to the other remaining two clients.